# ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1006 Unknown Host whils installing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I want to install Eclipse but keep getting error `ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1006 Unknown Host`. I try installing latest Eclipse version and jdk `13.0.2`

is there any solution? thanks.

here's the full log:

```
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 17.0.2+8
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2022-03
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.23.0.v20220301-0958, build=5396, branch=0ca218831ae58471d57f6865eb1ac482255de190
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.23.0.v20220301-0958, build=5396, branch=0ca218831ae58471d57f6865eb1ac482255de190
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.18.0.v20220301-0958, build=5396, branch=0ca218831ae58471d57f6865eb1ac482255de190
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2022-03))
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Offline = false
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Mirrors = true
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Resolving 17 requirements from 3 repositoriesto D:\eclipse\java-2022-03\eclipse
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.23.0,5.0.0) (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=macosx)(osgi.ws=cocoa))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux)(osgi.ws=gtk))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx)(osgi.ws=cocoa))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.ws=win32))))
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.23.0,5.0.0)
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.23.0,5.0.0)
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2022-03/202203101200
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/202203161000
[2022-03-26 12:04:32] Repository https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2022-03-26 12:04:33] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1006 Unknown Host: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03/202203161000/content.xml
java.net.UnknownHostException: download.eclipse.org
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:43)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:118)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:396)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:158)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:168)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:136)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:175)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:133)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement$1.proceed(ExecChainElement.java:57)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
  at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:75)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient5.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:251)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:71)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2022-03-26 12:04:33]
```

Comment: UnknownHostException for a well known host like `download.eclipse.org` points to a problem with your networking setup.